# Hosting front end on Vercel and back end on another service

Tags: web-hosting

I have a react JS application with Tailwind CSS  on the front end and Express and MySQL on the back end. I'm just a confused on the hosting of back end.

I currently deployed my front end on Vercel and it works fine.

Will I need to purchase another domain name if I need to host the back end and database elsewhere?  Alternatively, what's the best way of hosting this type of app?